# python AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'balance_label'

Tags: python, attributes

I can't seem to figure out why I can't update the label text.
But after a day... I figured I'd ask for help
self.balance_label['text'] = "Text updated" gives me: AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'balance_label'

I'm using 2 separate script.

file 1

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.constants import *
import os.path

_script = sys.argv[0]
_location = os.path.dirname(_script)

import trade_helper_support

_bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
_fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
_compcolor = 'gray40' # X11 color: #666666
_ana1color = '#c3c3c3' # Closest X11 color: 'gray76'
_ana2color = 'beige' # X11 color: #f5f5dc
_tabfg1 = 'black' 
_tabfg2 = 'black' 
_tabbg1 = 'grey75' 
_tabbg2 = 'grey89' 
_bgmode = 'light' 

class root:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''

        top.geometry("600x450+468+138")
        top.minsize(120, 1)
        top.maxsize(3844, 1061)
        top.resizable(1,  1)
        top.title("Trade Helper v1.0")
        top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")

        self.top = top


        self.menubar = tk.Menu(top,font="TkMenuFont",bg=_bgcolor,fg=_fgcolor)
        top.configure(menu = self.menubar)

        self.Get_balance_button = tk.Button(self.top)
        self.Get_balance_button.place(relx=0.283, rely=0.689, height=44
                , width=127)
        self.Get_balance_button.configure(activebackground="beige")
        self.Get_balance_button.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Get_balance_button.configure(background="#e35e8c")
        self.Get_balance_button.configure(command=trade_helper_support.get_balance)
        self.Get_balance_button.configure(compound='left')
        self.Get_balance_button.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Get_balance_button.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Get_balance_button.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Get_balance_button.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Get_balance_button.configure(pady="0")
        self.Get_balance_button.configure(text='''get balance''')

        self.balance_label = tk.Label(self.top)
        self.balance_label.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.711, height=31, width=74)
        self.balance_label.configure(anchor='w')
        self.balance_label.configure(background="#ffffff")
        self.balance_label.configure(compound='left')
        self.balance_label.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.balance_label.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.balance_label.configure(text='''Balance''')


    def settext(self):
        print('here')
        self.balance_label['text'] = "Text updated"

def start_up():
    trade_helper_support.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    trade_helper_support.main()
```

file 2

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.constants import *
import trade_helper


def main(*args):
    '''Main entry point for the application.'''
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.protocol( 'WM_DELETE_WINDOW' , root.destroy)
    # Creates a toplevel widget.
    global _top1, _w1
    _top1 = root
    _w1 = trade_helper.root(_top1)
    root.mainloop()


def get_balance(*args):
    print('trade_helper_support.get_balance')
    trade_helper.root.settext(root)

    for arg in args:
        print ('    another arg:', arg)
    sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    trade_helper.start_up()
```

I'd like the label text to change on button click.

It works when my function is inside the class but not the way I have it now.

i want file2 to to hold main code and file 1 to be the GUI only code

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution...

```
def get_balance(*args):

    print('trade_helper_support.get_balance')
    _w1.balance_label['text'] = "Text updated"
```